# UIScrollView to start at bottom view

Tags: ios, iphone, uiviewcontroller, uiscrollview

I am new in IOS Program.

I have UIscrollview with 2 vertical views and would like the page to load automatically on the 2nd/bottom view and to scroll upwards

here is my code for UIScrollView:

```
// Set up ScrollView

    UIScrollView *scrollview = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];

    NSInteger numberOfViews = 2;
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfViews; i++) {
        CGFloat y = i * self.view.frame.size.height;
        UIView *pageView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, y, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
        [scrollview addSubview:pageView];

    scrollview.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height *numberOfViews);
    scrollview.bounces = NO;

    [self.view addSubview:scrollview];
```

}

Comment: Simply set the `contentOffset` after setting it's `contentSize`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are creating that scrollview in viewDidLoad - just add this code into viewDidAppear and set up proper animation duration:

```
[scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height)];

[UIView animateWithDuration:5.0 animations:^{

    [scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointZero];

}];
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this in viewDidLoad:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];    

    CGPoint contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height);
    scrollView.contentOffset = contentOffset;
}
```

and in viewDidAppear:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    CGPoint contentOffset = CGPointZero;
    [scrollView setContentOffset:contentOffset animated:true];
}
```